# Deploying Storybooks in Turborepo to Chromatic

Tags: storybook, monorepo, turborepo, chromatic

We have a monorepo where AppA is consuming PackageB and both AppA and PackageB are from same workspace. When building the storybook locally, everything is ok but when try to deploy to Chromatic, it throws error that PackageB is not found.

I think that's because we are running chromatic separately for both subrepo. Is there a way to deploy both subrepo to Chromatic without facing the issue above?